# How to use fs in Mocha unit tests?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I'm trying to write a unit test that will get a list of files from the static folder of my project and pass the list to a function.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import FileAdder from '@/components/FileAdder'
//var fs = require('fs')
var path = '../../static/documents'
var fs = require('fs')

describe('FileAdder.vue', () => {

    it('should get a list of files from the static folder', () => {
    const Constructor = Vue.extend(FileAdder)
    const vm = new Constructor().$mount()
    fs.readdir(path, function(err, list){
        console.log(list)
    })

    })

})
```

I can't use `fs` in this code, however (probably because of security concerns?).  I get an error when running the test:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Cannot find module "fs"
```

But this code doesn't need to be executed on the client side - it's just for my local dev/testing server.  What sort of tests should I be running to accomplish this?  Is Mocha the wrong tool?

Comment: `fs` is built in nodejs module it is not available in browser. Take a look at https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS